# Agile Web Development With Rails, Iteration F4, Cart and Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, awdwr

I am reading the book Agile Web Development With Rails 4 and I have come across an undesirable effect in Iteration F4: "Hiding an Empty Cart" with showing the cart on the sidebar when there are previously no items in the cart.

With the standard code from the book, there is a bit of delay that I'm not sure is supposed to be there. I screen captured the effect. (see [here](http://quick.as/8dgph8g8))

here is the opposing code:

```
if ($('#cart tr').length == 1) { $('#cart').show('blind', 1000); }
```

I have found a solution that I will post as the answer, but I have to wait as I do not have enough reputation yet... Hopefully I'm not breaking any SO rules. I apologize if I am!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys!

I figured out that the 'blind' affect was what was causing the weird delay as shown in my question.

Here is the fixed code:

```
if ($('#cart tr').length == 1) { $('#cart').show(0) }
```

and the desired result [here](http://quick.as/vaaltlxp)